# How force IntelliJ to keep showing deleted files?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project that generates some Java files.
When i run a build, such java files are deleted, then regenerated. In the moment when one of such files is deleted, the tab showing it in IntelliJ disappears, so I must re-open it (there is not even a "recent closed files" list that helps me in that!).

So I keep the generated files open in Notepad++ (the best editor in the universe; it also keeps a list of the most recent closed files).
Notepad++ keeps open the files, if they are deleted by another program, when I click on them I get a question, more or less like this: «This file was deleted. Do you want to close or keep displaying it?»

Is possible to have a similar behaviour in IntelliJ instead to see files disappearing?
In the *closing policy* in *settings → Editor → Editor tabs* there is nothing similar.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible. There is a request you can vote up and follow for updates: [IDEABKL-7092](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-7092).

Comment: It's from 2014... :D